# Distribute divs vertically

Tags: html, css

How do you distribute child elements vertically evenly? For example, if I have a div with 3 input fields, each set to 100% width, I wish them to be distributed evenly in three rows, i.e 33.33% high as in the picture. Also, if there are 2 fields, I wish them to be in two rows each 50% high without explicitly setting them as such. Any ideas?

[image]
Currently my code bunches all the input fields at the top as in the snippet below.

```css
input { width: 60%;}
.whole-container { height: 300px;background: yellow;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="whole-container">
    <form id="login-form" method="POST">
      <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" id="cf-nameInput">
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email" id="cf-emailInput">
      <input name="tel" type="tel" placeholder="Phone number" id="cf-phoneInput">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If any of the answers, answer your question, please accept it so it will help to other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flex:

```css
input { 
  width: 60%;
}

.whole-container { 
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

.whole-container form {
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="whole-container">
    <form id="login-form" method="POST">
      <div><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" id="cf-nameInput"></div>
      <div><input name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email" id="cf-emailInput"></div>
      <div><input name="tel" type="tel" placeholder="Phone number" id="cf-phoneInput"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Flex can help you:

```css
form {height:300px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  justify-content:space-around;
  background:yellow;
  }
input {
 width: 60%;}
```

```html
<div class="whole-container">
  <form id="login-form" method="POST">
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" id="cf-nameInput">
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email" id="cf-emailInput">
            <input name="tel" type="tel" placeholder="Phone number" id="cf-phoneInput">
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution that doesn't use `display:flex` you can check the following example:

```css
input { width: 60%;}
#login-form { height:100%; }
.whole-container { display:block; height: 300px;background: yellow;}
.container { min-height:33%; }
```

```html
<div class="whole-container">
  <form id="login-form" method="POST">
            <div class="container">
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" id="cf-nameInput">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email" id="cf-emailInput">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            <input name="tel" type="tel" placeholder="Phone number" id="cf-phoneInput">
            </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

That basically just wraps the `input` inside a `div`, then you assign the div's height based on the amount of input you need (in this case 33%)

Comment: This puts first input on the top edge while the author wanted it to have a margin from the top edge. I guess  inputs should be additionally vertically centered inside divs

Comment: he can position the input using some additional css, for example adding to the input css position:absolute; bottom:0; will align all the input on the bottom, same goes if he wants to vertical align them inside a container.
I've posted the example because if someone needs to support old browsers display:flex won't work